# pass in gretty options on the command line

Tags: gradle, jetty, gretty

Does anybody know if there is an easy way to override the gretty, or any gradle configuration on the command line?

(the ones here: http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Gretty-configuration.html)

I have tried this

```
gradle -Dgretty.httpPort=8111 :web:jettyRun
```

but it still runs on port 8080.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it like below,

```
gretty {
   if(project.hasProperty('portNumber')){ // if variable passed use it
       httpPort=Integer.parseInt(portNumber)
   }
   else{ // if it is not passed use a default port
      httpPort=8080
   }
...
}
```

And when you want to use a specific port `gradle  ...  -PportNumber=8111`